# What are folks doing with extra microSD card adapters?

Tags: fieldwork, best-practice

With the amount of ST600 deployments we do, I order a lot of microSD cards. Every time they come with an adapter, which I do not need more than 2 or 3 on hand. I have a dedicated microSD card case to keep my spare cards in and organized.

I'm ordering in Europe.  If you are aware of a place from which I can buy SD cards without the excess electronic waste, I'd love to hear it. Alternatively,  is there a good place to donate this type of electronic?

[image: box full of microSD card adapters]

Answer (score 0):

As I'm designing/building also my own recorders, I'm always speculating to use these adapters directly to circuit boards. It turns out that all pins can be accessed with 2.54 mm spaced pin-headers.

Otherwise, I agree that microSD cards are sold with adapters is only increasing plastic waste.

On the other hand, I keep my used microSD cards always in adapter. They increase the volume and are easier to find.